# Will emulator work for testing BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to do some testing to see if I can detect a callstate change by extending from BroadcastReceiver and listening to a state change, however, when testing in my android emulator (API 32), I'm unable to get it to ever trigger my onReceive method in my class that extends BroadcastReceiver. Is this a misunderstanding of mine in that emulators don't trigger BroadcastReceiver for simulated emulator calls or have I set up my class improperly? I've struggled to find anything regarding how to test this correctly.

Class that extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            // action performed for outgoing calls here
        }
        else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }
            // additional logic here
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest where I register the receiver:

```
// This is above my <application> section just inside of <manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
// This is inside my <application> section
<receiver android:name=".background.PhonecallReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution actually. Emulator does work for testing this. It wasn't updating my permissions properly however, so I had to manually tell the emulator to allow permissions. I'll have to fix that piece for future users it looks like.